# Getting maximum values and x,y coordinates from a list of list without replacement

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have a list that contains six lists which each contain 6 floats. I want to find the max value from the overall set, record its x and y values (for lack of a better term...as if I am considering the list of list a graph) and then remove that list from consideration so that each element in the outer list can only be chosen once.

I came up with the following method to do it, which works. But I am afraid it is terribly inelegant and there is probably a much better way to go about this.

Original list

```
[[5.468295520651542, 37.0564281559046, 43.455497382198956, 3.781268179173938, 0.11634671320535195, 10.122164048865619],
 [7.3991031390134525, 48.87892376681614, 26.00896860986547, 4.708520179372197, 5.829596412556054, 7.174887892376682],
 [30.382775119617225, 2.6315789473684212, 0.7177033492822966, 64.5933014354067, 1.4354066985645932, 0.23923444976076555],
 [5.112474437627812, 2.8629856850715747, 6.952965235173824, 3.476482617586912, 76.27811860940696, 5.316973415132924],
 [85.98979013045944, 6.693136698808849, 3.5734543391945546, 1.5314804310833805, 1.1344299489506522, 1.0777084515031197],
 [5.565529622980251, 65.1705565529623, 2.5733093955715143, 5.326152004787552, 11.789347695990426, 9.57510472770796]]
```

My Code

```
maxmaxlist=[]
maxxlist=[]
maxylist=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    maxlist=[]
    xlist=[]
    for j in range(0,len(templist)):
        temp = (max(templist[j]))
        maxlist.append(temp)
        xlist.append(templist[j].index(temp))

    temp = max(maxlist)
    maxmaxlist.append(temp)

    temp2 = maxlist.index(temp)
    maxylist.append((templist[temp2]).index(temp))
    maxxlist.append(temp2)
    templist[temp2] = [0]
print maxmaxlist, maxxlist, maxylist
```

Comment: please provide the output you expect from your input.

Comment: @paul-panzer below, reproduced my exact results with much less code than I used!

Comment: nope, paul-panzer code produces 3 numbers, you're code is producing 3 lists of 6 numbers.

Comment: no. I think that you are looking at the wrong answer. The code produces three lists.

Comment: Indeed, Paul, not Patrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pythonic approach would be:

```
lst = [[5.468295520651542, 37.0564281559046, 43.455497382198956, 3.781268179173938, 0.11634671320535195, 10.122164048865619], [7.3991031390134525, 48.87892376681614, 26.00896860986547, 4.708520179372197, 5.829596412556054, 7.174887892376682], [30.382775119617225, 2.6315789473684212, 0.7177033492822966, 64.5933014354067, 1.4354066985645932, 0.23923444976076555], [5.112474437627812, 2.8629856850715747, 6.952965235173824, 3.476482617586912, 76.27811860940696, 5.316973415132924], [85.98979013045944, 6.693136698808849, 3.5734543391945546, 1.5314804310833805, 1.1344299489506522, 1.0777084515031197], [5.565529622980251, 65.1705565529623, 2.5733093955715143, 5.326152004787552, 11.789347695990426, 9.57510472770796]]

for m, x in sorted(((max(l), x) for x, l in enumerate(lst)), reverse=True):
  m, y = max((val, y) for y, val in enumerate(lst[x]))
  print(x, y, '-->', m)
```

with the following output:

```
4 0 --> 85.98979013045944
3 4 --> 76.27811860940696
5 1 --> 65.1705565529623
2 3 --> 64.5933014354067
1 1 --> 48.87892376681614
0 2 --> 43.455497382198956
```

If you need to store your final data in a list, replace the `for` loop by a comprehension list:

```
m_x_y = [(m, x, max((val, y) for y,val in enumerate(lst[x]))[1]) for m, x in
         sorted(((max(l), x) for x,l in enumerate(lst)), reverse=True)]
print(m_x_y)
```

gives:

```
[(85.98979013045944, 4, 0), (76.27811860940696, 3, 4),
 (65.1705565529623,  5, 1), (64.5933014354067,  2, 3),
 (48.87892376681614, 1, 1), (43.45549738219896, 0, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `enumerate` through the lists and sublists to get the indices, and use `max` to find the maximum.

```
l = [[5.468295520651542, 37.0564281559046, 43.455497382198956, 3.781268179173938, 0.11634671320535195, 10.122164048865619], [7.3991031390134525, 48.87892376681614, 26.00896860986547, 4.708520179372197, 5.829596412556054, 7.174887892376682], [30.382775119617225, 2.6315789473684212, 0.7177033492822966, 64.5933014354067, 1.4354066985645932, 0.23923444976076555], [5.112474437627812, 2.8629856850715747, 6.952965235173824, 3.476482617586912, 76.27811860940696, 5.316973415132924], [85.98979013045944, 6.693136698808849, 3.5734543391945546, 1.5314804310833805, 1.1344299489506522, 1.0777084515031197], [5.565529622980251, 65.1705565529623, 2.5733093955715143, 5.326152004787552, 11.789347695990426, 9.57510472770796]]

maximum, max_x, max_y = max((n, x, y) 
                            for x, subl in enumerate(l) 
                            for y, n in enumerate(subl))

# 85.98979013045944, 4, 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following reproduces the result of your code:

```
LL = [[5.468295520651542, 37.0564281559046, 43.455497382198956, 3.781268179173938, 0.11634671320535195, 10.122164048865619],
 [7.3991031390134525, 48.87892376681614, 26.00896860986547, 4.708520179372197, 5.829596412556054, 7.174887892376682],
 [30.382775119617225, 2.6315789473684212, 0.7177033492822966, 64.5933014354067, 1.4354066985645932, 0.23923444976076555],
 [5.112474437627812, 2.8629856850715747, 6.952965235173824, 3.476482617586912, 76.27811860940696, 5.316973415132924],
 [85.98979013045944, 6.693136698808849, 3.5734543391945546, 1.5314804310833805, 1.1344299489506522, 1.0777084515031197],
 [5.565529622980251, 65.1705565529623, 2.5733093955715143, 5.326152004787552, 11.789347695990426, 9.57510472770796]]


# find max index of each sublist
mxy = [max(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__) for L in LL]
# and the corresponding maxima
mx = [L[y] for L, y in zip(LL, mxy)]
# indirectly (i.e. by index) sort maxima in descending order
mxx = sorted(range(len(LL)), key=mx.__getitem__, reverse=True)
# use index to rearrange mxy and mx
mxy = [mxy[x] for x in mxx]
mx = [mx[x] for x in mxx]

mx
# [85.98979013045944, 76.27811860940696, 65.1705565529623, 64.5933014354067, 48.87892376681614, 43.455497382198956]
mxy
# [0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2]
mxx
# [4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```

Or, for afficionados of the one-liner (inspired by @PatrickHaugh; Python3 only):

```
from itertools import count, repeat

mx, mxy, mxx = zip(*sorted(map(max, map(zip, LL, map(count, repeat(0)), map(repeat, count()))), reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given input

```
In [1]: L = [ [5.468295520651542, 37.0564281559046, 43.455497382198956, 3.781268179173938, 0.11634671320535195, 10.122164048865619],
    ...: [7.3991031390134525, 48.87892376681614, 26.00896860986547, 4.708520179372197, 5.829596412556054, 7.174887892376682],
    ...: [30.382775119617225, 2.6315789473684212, 0.7177033492822966, 64.5933014354067, 1.4354066985645932, 0.23923444976076555],
    ...: [5.112474437627812, 2.8629856850715747, 6.952965235173824, 3.476482617586912, 76.27811860940696, 5.316973415132924],
    ...: [85.98979013045944, 6.693136698808849, 3.5734543391945546, 1.5314804310833805, 1.1344299489506522, 1.0777084515031197],
    ...: [5.565529622980251, 65.1705565529623, 2.5733093955715143, 5.326152004787552, 11.789347695990426, 9.57510472770796]]
    ...:
```

statement

```
In [2]: [ (x,*reversed(max([ (m, y) for (y,m) in enumerate(l)]))) for (x,l) in enumerate(L) ]
```

produces

```
Out[2]: 
[(0, 2, 43.455497382198956),
 (1, 1, 48.87892376681614),
 (2, 3, 64.5933014354067),
 (3, 4, 76.27811860940696),
 (4, 0, 85.98979013045944),
 (5, 1, 65.1705565529623)]
```